# How do i delete player score after point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I have a problem and indeed I save my highscore in playerprefs with setfloat and call the highscore in the menu with getfloat the problem is that it then shows me in the highscore eg 1220 and then just another .123 so 1220.123 as shown in the picture how do I delete the numbers after the point?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI0Hp.jpg)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can cast it to an int to round it up

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where the name of the PlayerPref is "Score" you can update this to match what you have named you PlayerPref.

The .ToString("f0") is a string formatting method that will return a string without the decimal places.

```
string score = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Score", 0).ToString("f0");
```

Another option is to use the SetInt() and GetInt() method of PlayerPrefs. You can use this if you don't need the decimal point. However, you'll need to provide this method with an integer and not a float so you would have to covert it beforehand. I think you can actually use GetInt() even if you used SetFloat() to set the value.

Comment: Thank you so much